# JqTreeGrid columns reordering

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

how can i set the columns reordering in java script. i saw a demo on trirand.net which show the columns reordering from the server side see the demo [here](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx)

but how can i set this functionality in the java script .if you check the functionality in tab from left side and click on reorder or re size columns you can see that functionality ...

thanks a lot in advance . ,

zahaiby

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pure JavaScript`, it is really dirty and a little hard! But using `jQuery` it is easy :-)

Please take a look on `table sorter`. You can do that by the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
});
```

For the example visit this [website](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want that user can drag a column and replace with any columns of the grid means swap the columns ...

Comment: @zahaibzahaib: but the website which you linked, is not support such a property which you mentioned in the comment. Please ask you questions carefully!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** : 
You can use the `sortable` property of jqGrid to do the same.
Set the`sortable` property as  `true` option to the grid properties.

```
sortable: true
```

Comment: thanks for your reply  but i want that user can drag a column and replace with any columns of the grid means swap the columns ...

Comment: @zahaibzahaib. just add `sortable:true` and try